# program runs differently depending on the use of cos or cosd( matlab functions)

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

My Matlab program works properly when the angles are in radians and thus I call cos and sin functions in the code below. When the angles are in degrees and thus I call cosd and sind, my program doesn't work as expected.

```
%Initial configuration of robot manipulator
%There are 7DOF( degrees of freedom) - 1 prismatic, 6 revolute
%vector qd represents these DOF
%indexes    : d = gd( 1), q1 = qd( 2), ..., q6 = qd( 7)
qd( 1)      =       1;      % d  = 1 m
qd( 2)      =  pi / 2;      % q1 = 90 degrees
qd( 3 : 6)  =       0;      % q2 = ... = q6 = 0 degrees
qd( 7)      = -pi / 2;
%Initial position of each joint - the tool is manipulated separately
%calculate sinusoids and cosines
[ c, s] = sinCos( qd( 2 : length( qd)));
```

and here is the sinCos code

```
function [ c, s] = sinCos( angles)
%takes a row array of angles in degrees and returns all the
%sin( angles( 1) + angles( 2) + ... + angles( i)) and
%cos( angles( 1) + angles( 2) + ... + angles( i)) where
%1 <= i <= length( angles)
sum = 0;
s   = zeros( 1, length( angles));       % preallocate for speed
c   = zeros( 1, length( angles));
for i = 1 : length( angles)
    sum = sum + angles( i);
    s( i) = sin( sum);     % s( i) = sin( angles( 1) + ... + angles( i))
    c( i) = cos( sum);     % c( i) = cos( angles( 1) + ... + angles( i))
end % for
% end function
```

The whole program is ~ 700 lines, so I displayed only the part above. My program simulates the motion of a redundant robot that tries to reach a goal while avoiding two obstacles.

So, does my problem relates to cos and cosd? Do cos and cosd have a different behavior that affects my program? Or I have a bug in my program that is revealed?

Comment: Looks like you've got some angular values hardcoded in radians (`qd(2) = pi/2` for example)... this makes me suspect that you're failing to change the entire program to use degrees instead of radians.  If you don't change **all** angular values to degrees you'll have problems.  It is unlikely that you've discovered a bug in `sind` and `cosd` though.

Answer (score 0):

By difference, do you mean something on the order of less than .00001? Because extremely small errors can be discounted due to floating point arithmetic errors. Computers are not able to accurately calculate decimal numbers with as much accuracy as they are able to store them. It is for this reason you should never directly compare two floating-point numbers; a range of error must be allowed for. You can read more about this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Machine_precision_and_backward_error_analysis

If your error is greater than .0001 or so, you might consider searching for a bug in your program. If you are not already using matlab to convert units for you, consider doing so as I have found that it can eliminate many 'obvious' errors (and in some cases increase precision).